# Normalize HTTP URI

Tags: ruby, uri

I get URIs from Akamai's log files that include entries such as the following:

```
/foo/jim/jam
/foo/jim/jam?
/foo/./jim/jam
/foo/bar/../jim/jam
/foo/jim/jam?autho=<randomstring>&file=jam
```

I would like to normalize all of these to the same entry, under the rules:

- If there is a query string, strip `autho` and `file` from it.
- If the query string is empty, remove the trailing `?`.
- Directory entries for `./` should be removed.
- Directory entries for `<fulldir>/../` should be removed.

I would have thought that the [`URI`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) library for Ruby would cover this, but:

- It does not provide any mechanism for parsing parts of the query string. (Not that this is hard to do, nor standard.)
- It does not remove a trailing `?` if the query string is emptied.

  ```
  URI.parse('/foo?jim').tap{ |u| u.query='' }.to_s #=> "/foo?"
  ```
- The `normalize` method does not clean up `.` or `..` in the path.

So, failing an official library, I find myself writing a regex-based solution.

```
def normalize(path)
  result = path.dup
  path.sub! /(?<=\?).+$/ do |query|
    query.split('&').reject do |kv|
      %w[ autho file ].include?(kv[/^[^=]+/])
    end.join('&')
  end
  path.sub! /\?$/, ''
  path.sub!(/^[^?]+/){ |path| path.gsub(%r{[^/]+/\.\.},'').gsub('/./','/') }
end
```

It happens to work for the test cases I've listed above, but with 450,000 paths to clean up I cannot hand check them all.

- Is there any glaring error with the above, considering likely log file entries?
- Is there a better way to accomplish the same that leans on proven parsing techniques instead of my hand-rolled regex?

Comment: `CGI::parse` and `URI::split` could help

Comment: result is not used in the example above, only path is doing anything, would it not be better something like this def normalize(path)
  path.gsub(%r{/+}, '/') do |query|
    query.split('&').reject do |kv|
      %w[autho file].include?(kv[/^[^=]+/])
    end.join('&')
  end
  path.sub! /\?$/, ''
  path.sub!(/^[^?]+/) { |path| path.gsub(%r{[^/]+/\.\.}, '').gsub('/./', '/') }
end   or similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem will normalize these for you:

```
require 'addressable/uri'

# normalize relative paths
uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://example.com/foo/bar/../jim/jam')
puts uri.normalize.to_s #=> "http://example.com/foo/jim/jam"

# removes trailing ?
uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://example.com/foo/jim/jam?')
puts uri.normalize.to_s #=> "http://example.com/foo/jim/jam"

# leaves empty parameters alone
uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://example.com/foo/jim/jam?jim')
puts uri.normalize.to_s #=> "http://example.com/foo/jim/jam?jim"

# remove specific query parameters
uri = Addressable::URI.parse('http://example.com/foo/jim/jam?autho=<randomstring>&file=jam')
cleaned_query = uri.query_values
cleaned_query.delete('autho')
cleaned_query.delete('file')
uri.query_values = cleaned_query
uri.normalize.to_s #=> "http://example.com/foo/jim/jam"
```

Comment: This is great, but for one (very small) problem: requesting/setting the `query_values` causes the query values to be sorted alphabetically. Thus, round-tripping an "OK" URL through this unnecessarily changes it (to something that is functionally equivalent, but different).

Answer (score 2):

Something that is *REALLY* important, like, *ESSENTIAL* to remember, is that a URL/URI is a protocol, a host, a file-path to a resource, followed by options/parameters being passed to the resource being referenced. (For the pedantic, there are other, optional, things in there too but this is sufficient.)

We can extract the path from a URL by parsing it using the [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) class, and using the [`path`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Generic.html#method-i-path-3D) method. Once we have the path, we have either an absolute path or a relative path based on the root of the site. Dealing with absolute paths is easy:

```
require 'uri'

%w[
  /foo/jim/jam
  /foo/jim/jam?
  /foo/./jim/jam
  /foo/bar/../jim/jam
  /foo/jim/jam?autho=<randomstring>&file=jam
].each do |url|
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  path = uri.path
  puts File.absolute_path(path)
end
# >> /foo/jim/jam
# >> /foo/jim/jam
# >> /foo/jim/jam
# >> /foo/jim/jam
# >> /foo/jim/jam
```

Because the paths are file paths based on the root of the server, we can play games using Ruby's [`File.absolute_path`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/File.html#method-c-absolute_path) method to normalize the '.' and '..' away and get a true absolute path. This will break if there are more `..` (parent directory) than the chain of directories, but you shouldn't find that in extracted paths since that would also break the server/browser ability to serve/request/receive resources.

It gets a bit more "interesting" when dealing with relative paths but File is still our friend then, but that's a different question.

Comment: `URI#normalize!` could benefit from this. In 2.3.0 it just changes '' to '/' and downcases the scheme and host.